# WordPress add_action error call_user_func_array()

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm attempting to put a hook in a Visual Form Builder plugin.
Documentation told me to create a php page in the plugin directory with the following

```
add_action( 'vfbp_after_save_entry', 'filter_vfbp_after_save_entry', 10, 2 );


function filter_vfbp_after_save_entry( $entry_ID, $form_ID ) {
// execute some custom code here
   $friends = 'email@example.com';
   mail( $friends, 'New Entries', 'We just got new entries for our contest!' );

  return $entry_ID;
```

}

I keep on getting the following error:

Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, non-static method allow_php_in_posts::shortcode_advanced() should not be called statically in

Anyone know how to solve this or point me in the right direction?

Comment: The code you provided and the error message seem completely unrelated on the face of it.

Comment: your right.  i deleted the source and still got the error.  Had to deactivate plugins till the error was removed.